# How to Setup IIS 7 and LDAP Authentication

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, ldap

Hi IIS and LDAP Experts!

I will need to configure IIS 7 so that when a user go to my intranet website it will popup a login box asking for the user to enter his/her intranet ID and password which is in LDAP. My source codes are in raw PHP running on IIS.

I have tried to enable Basic Authentication but it only allows some users to login belonging to the same region, and other can't login. We have different regions ("AP", "NA", "EMEA", "CN").

I have also tried to enable Windows Authentication but again it only allows some users to login belonging to the same region as the server is.

Can you please kindly help me how to configure IIS so that it will prompt a login box and it will authenticate users to LDAP? I don't want to use any programming like PHP or ASP.net to login to LDAP. Can I configure it only using IIS? Please really need your advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/, http://superuser.com/, ect. http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology ??? SO issnt the place to ask this - too broad and not a direct programming question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @DanielBrose ok thank you will not post next time in SO for non programming questions.

Comment: please post a self-answer then accept it, ideally sharing some link or referance to how you solved it, to improve SEO and combat unanswered dead topics.